# Difference between Matsumura's Commutative Algebra and Commutative Ring Theory

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

I am a beginner in more advanced algebra and my question is very simple, I would like to know the difference between these books of the same author, Hideyuki Matsumura

- [Commutative Ring Theory (Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521367646)
- [Commutative Algebra (Mathematics lecture note series ; 56)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805370269)

Comment: In the future, you should include **all necessary information** in your post. Your title says nothing substantive, the text of your links says nothing substantive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is essentially identical to this MathOverflow thread:

[Matsumura: “Commutative Algebra” versus “Commutative Ring Theory”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25411/1916)